# C++ Dynamically allocated std::vector

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, vector, allocation

I'm a C++ newbie and I am working on university project Driver Book in C++.
I am using vector for the first time and I would like to make it work with dynamic memory allocation.

I have vector declared like this:

```
vector <item> book;
```

What is needed to make it work with dynamic memory allocation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate on *make it work with dynamic memory allocation*! In what respect is declaring `vector <item> book` not sufficient for your needs?

Comment: The vector uses dynamic allocation internally there is not much need to really use dynamic allocation on any standard library containers.

Comment: vector does work with dynamic allocation, always. You don't have to do anything to make it so. I guess really your question is 'how to I use a vector?'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done. `vector` already internally dynamically allocates when you `push_back` into it.

Comment: I want to point out that when others say "vector already internally dynamically allocates when you push_back into it", it means that objects pushed into the vector are dynamically allocated, not the vector itself is automatically dynamically allocated upon creation. If a vector is created inside function f without using the "new" keyword, and you return a pointer to the vector from f, it'd still lead to dangling pointers.

Answer (score 6):

To eleborate a bit more: `vector<T>` is a resizable array, which can hold objects of type `T`.
It internally get memory dynamically. Now if you want to create the vector with dynamic allocation you are always free to use `vector<item>* myVec = new vector<item>();`
Although generally you'll never need to create a `vector` dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

The vector uses dynamic memory allocation internally. So all you need to do is put elements in it:

```
item i = ....;
book.push_back(i);
```

See [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for more things you can do with a vector.

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out that when others say "vector already internally dynamically allocates when you push_back into it", it means that objects pushed into the vector are dynamically allocated, not the vector itself is automatically dynamically allocated upon creation.

For example, if you want a vector created inside a function to persist, below code will lead to undefined behavior because the vector itself is not automatically dynamically allocated. After the return, the vector's memory location will automatically be cleaned up. The reference will be referencing garbage.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int>& f() {
  vector<int> v = vector<int>({4, 5, 6});
  
  return v;
}

int main() {
    
    vector<int>& b = f();

    
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

If you hope to keep the vector in existence even as the function returns, you still need to use dynamically allocated memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
struct Node {
    int a;
    Node(int a) : a(a) {}
};
using namespace std;

vector<int>& f() {
  vector<int>& v = *new vector<int>({4, 5, 6});
  
  return v;
}

int main() {
    
    vector<int>& b = f();
    
    vector<int>* bptr = &b;
    
    cout<<b[2]<<endl;
  
    
    delete bptr;
    
    
    
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```